# CSS Selector - Target DT only when followed by DD

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am attempting to target a `<dt>` only when followed by `<dd>`. I know there is a preceding selector, however I can not find a CSS method of targeting the `<dt>`. I know this is possible with JavaScript, but would rather keep it to CSS Selectors if at all possible.

This does not have to function in IE6 or below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: Also, I should note that `dd` should be preceded by `dt`.

Comment: After reading through the linked question, I still don't have a solution. As stated, I know you can target an element when preceded by another element; however, I need to target an element only when it is followed by another element.

Answer (score 1):

I thought maybe dt ~ dd would work, but it actually functions similar to +, only not quite as specific.

After looking at the W3C css selector document http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html, I can say with a great degree of confidence that what you are wanting to do is not possible with just CSS. It is also missing a way to get the parent selector. Maybe in CSS4...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a similar solution for a similar problem. In my case I want to select the last `dd` in a `dd` group, so therefore any `dd` that is followed by `dt` or is the first child of the `dl` (since, for whatever reason, this is allowed).

I also haven't found a pure CSS solution. I was toying around with multiple rules such that all that would remain would be (in your case) the "empty" `dt`, but nothing all inclusive.

If I get that to work, I'll let you know. Otherwise, the solution that is selector-like (thus keeping any other selector syntax intact) is the jquery non-css `:has()` selector. So in your case:

```
$("dt:not(:has(+dd))").addClass("empty_def");
$("dt:has(+dd)").addClass("non_empty_def");
```

Comment: "so therefore any `dd` that... is the first child of the `dl`" Unless it's followed by another `dd`...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Good call.

Answer (score -3):

You want the sibling selector:

```
DT + DD { color : #00f; }
```

Doesn't work in IE6 but does in other browsers.

Comment: Fine, then use DD + DT {color: #00f;} instead

Comment: That would target the DT, when preceded by DD. I am looking to target the DT when it is followed by a DD.

Comment: This answer will not produce the desired result.